# How to show that $n^{-r} \sum_{j=1}^n (X_j - \mu) \rightarrow 0$ in probability

Tags: probability-theory, random-variables, law-of-large-numbers

I need your help to prove the following statement.

---

Let $X_1, \cdots X_n$ be stochasticaly independent, identically distributed random variables. Assume they have a finite expected value $\mu$ and a finite  variance $\sigma^2$. Show that the following equivalence holds:

$$
n^{-r} \sum_{j=1}^n (X_j - \mu) \ \longrightarrow \ 0 \ \text{in probability}\quad \iff \quad r>\frac{1}{2}
$$

---

**Research effort**

We have to consider the expression $P(|\sum_{j=1}^n(X_j-\mu)| \geq \epsilon \cdot n^r )$
We know that $(|\sum_{j=1}^n(X_j-\mu)| \geq \sum_{j=1}^n|X_j-\mu|| \geq \epsilon$
And with some other observations, it would be enough to prove that
$$
P(|X_1-\mu| \geq \epsilon \cdot n^{r-1})^n \rightarrow 0 \quad \text{in probability}
$$
It appears to me that I have not enough information about $X_1$' behaviour to prove this. Could you please give me a hint?

Answer (score 4):

Define $Y_n:=\frac 1{n^r}\sum_{j=1}^n(X_j-\mu)$. Since $\mathbb E(Y_n^2)=\frac 1{n^{2r-1}}\sigma^2$, there is convergence in probability when $r>1/2$.

For $r=1/2$, there is a well known theorem in probability theory which shows that we can't have convergence in probability to $0$.

Comment: I am interested in the case when $r=1/2$. Could you please give a reference for that well-known theorem? Thank you very much!

Comment: I meant the central limit theorem.

Comment: @DavideGiraudo What about the case $r<1/2$? I don't see what happens then.

Comment: It is a consequence of the case because $n^{-1/2}\sum_{j=1}^n(X_j-\mu)$ converges in distribution to something which is not degenerate.

Comment: @DavideGiraudo I dont understand why the case $r=1/2$ effects the case $r<1/2$. Could you please explain in more detail?

Comment: Call $S_n$ the partial sums. Then $n^{-1/2}S_n\to N$, where $N$ is normally distributed with non-zero variance. Hence we cannot have $n^{-1/2}S_n\to 0$ in probability. If you take a smaller exponent than $1/2$ instead of $1/2$ it is even worse.

Comment: @DavideGiraudo Sorry for asking so much, but what do you mean by even worse? I mean, it doesn't seem like a proof.

Comment: If $Y_n$ doesn't converge to $0$ in probability, then for each positive $\delta$, $n^\delta$ doesn't converge to $0$ in probability.